# Function to detect if a point is inside a 3d polygon on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

What is a function or algorithm to detect as fast as possible wheter a point lies inside a tridimensional polygon?

Comment: That depends on the system and library you're using. Could we get some more info please?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about specifically (neither a mathematician nor a graphics coder), but a search of your [near exact question text](https://www.google.com/search?q=algorithm+to+detect+as+fast+as+possible+wheter+a+point+lies+inside+a+tridimensional+polygon) found [Wikipedia's Delaunay triangulation entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), which points to this [project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/source/browse/src/js/poly2tri.js?repo=javascript).

Comment: I have already searched a lot and couldn't find this one!

Elliot, I'm specifially testing for Three.JS meshes, but I guess this is not relevant because I can convert them if necessary.

Comment: Is that what you need? I really don't know the subject. If this is what you need, I've recognized when you search Google for something, you really need to put yourself in the shoes of the person(s) who control/curate the information, and search for terms/phrases they would use/search for in the context of that subject; in other words, first understand their language/lingo/expressiveness (that's suitably unique enough to be useful in a search). It's probable that you were searching ineffectively until you literally just tried to verbalize it in a sentence. It happens to me, too.

Comment: No no, unfortunatelly it is not. I've been really bad at google lately. Not sure if this is me or their results are becoming worse. I'll keep trying.